# R loop naming different objects

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to create a loop for estimating the same regression in R for 20 times. I have tried to create a loop in which every regression is called in a different way, however I don't manage to have different objects (I get an error message). The code is the following.

```
for (i in 1:20){
fit_[i] <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=mydata)
}
```

Basically I would like to create many different objects (from fit_1 to fit_20) where I have my results stored.

Comment: Why can't you store it in an array? Why do you need different objects?

Comment: If you want variable with different name one way to do it is `assign(paste("fit_", i, sep=""), lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=mydata))`. However, as other comments suggest, using vector/list is preffered

Comment: What is your error message ?

Comment: Error in fit_[i] <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=mydata) : object 'fit_' not found

Comment: it's because you didn't initialized `fit_`

Comment: If you run the model 20 times, you will get the same result each time. You might as well do `rep(list(lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=mydata)), 20)`. Were you expecting 20 different results?

Comment: This is FAQ 7.21 (in the R FAQ: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f).  The most important part of that FAQ is the end where it says to use lists instead.  But if you (original poster) will be using different models in each step, there is a part of the FAQ that covers that as well.  Your eventual goal will probably be easier using lists and functions like `replicate` or `lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

Use double brackets `[[]]` to create a list instead:

```
fit_ <- list()
for (i in 1:20){
  fit_[[i]] <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=mydata)
}
```

Or use Roman's solution in the comments if you want to have separate objects `fit_1`, `fit_2`, etc.

Comment: It does not work also with the double brackets, the error is Error in fit_[i] <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=mydata) : 
  object 'fit_' not found

Comment: Notice that I have the line `fit_ <- NULL` first to create the object `fit_`.

Comment: Just a minor not, if you do `fit_ <- NULL` first, it will create a vector not a list.  For a resulting list you have to do `fit_ <- list()`

Comment: @RomanTsegelskyi You're right.  While both work, using `list()` is a better practice.